# How to send log in credentials and receive a html page in C# using a Windows Phone 8/8.1 app?

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone-8

I am trying to access a html page to scrape data from my Windows Phone 8. But first i need to send log-in credentials to it. I am currently using [htmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to scrape the data from the login page. I have tried to use WebBrowser instance to run in the background, but the html page is not automatically clickable and i cannot proceed.  After which i tried to use the HttpClient class to send data using PostAsync() method, which only recieves a HttpResponseMessage, with which i have no clue what to do, but i am successfully able to send the credential data using a HttpContent object.

```
var httpResponseMessage = await client1.PostAsync("https://www.webpage.com", content);
```

After that i have been massively unsuccessful in progressing forward.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You're basically trying to hack the HTML. Try using Fiddler to see what is getting sent via the manual login process and that might yield a clue so you can do it programmatically: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I use HttpClient class to communicate with a webservice in my project:

```
public async Task<string> httpPOST(string url, FormUrlEncodedContent content)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());
    string resp = "";
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

    try
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Task<string> getStringAsync = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        resp = await getStringAsync;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException)
    {
        resp = "NO_INTERNET";
    }

        return resp;
}
```

Here you can see how to retrieve the data. Hope it helps :)

Comment: What do the variables "lang" and "tesco_base_url" contain?

Comment: lang contains the language of the app (there are two supported languages). You can comment that out, I just showed how to send headers. tesco_base_url is an url like "http://google.com/".

Comment: Thank you so much. I actually did not require the headers or the tesco_base_url. The code works perfectly.

Comment: I have an extended question in relation to this question...
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29631680/accessing-a-html-page-that-is-in-a-tab-of-a-html-page-using-windows-phone-8-app)
Please advise. @WPMed