# Accessing a html page that is in a tab of a html page using Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, html, http, windows-phone-8

I am programming in C# and for Windows Phone 8. I am currently trying to access a html page (lets say an students subject grades[page 2]).

This html page is referenced by a `href` tag that is placed within another html page (the students home screen after log in [page 1]), which i have accessed using a `HttpClient` object with the help of a `POSTAsync` function.

I need to know a way by which i can programmatically click this specific link (from page 1 to page 2).

I know how to access the href content using the HTMLAgilityPack, but i don't know how to load "THAT"(page 2) HTML page which is specific and different to every individual. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to load the page in a browser or just get the html returned as the result of a function?

Comment: i need the Html document, since i have to remove content from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can access the href with the HTMLAgilityPack than you can simply call another POSTAsync with the url being the href link.

Comment: I need another help from you. It relates to the same topic. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645514/how-to-select-option-for-the-select-tag-on-a-html-page-using-windows-phone-8). @WPMed